# Reference a variable on HTML pages across Java Web Application

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring in a Java Web Application with Thymeleaf on standard HTML pages (not JSP). I have forms on several pages with several text inputs. I would like to reference some variable for maxlength on the text inputs. For example:

Current:

```
<input id='name' type='text' maxlength='20' />
```

Goal:

```
<input id='name' type='text' maxlength='${nameMaxlength}' />
```

I would prefer to put these in a file somewhere that my Java code can access, so that the client-side and server-side validation can reference the same values. Are there any best practices for this sort of functionality?

Comment: I would prefer not to put a variable into every session, attach a model object for it, or associate it with a particular locale (since it will be the same). Is there a way that thymeleaf can access a file on every site?

Comment: Are you using Spring the spring dialect with Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Thymeleaf with the Spring dialect you could do the following:

```
package somepackage;

public final class WebConsts {

   public static final int MAX_LENGTH = 20;

   private WebConsts(){}
}

<input id="name" type="text" th:maxlength="${T(somepackage.WebConsts).MAX_LENGTH}" />
```

The expression in maxlength is a standard Spring EL expression

Comment: I like this solution as it means you could reference the constant from something like a JSR303 Bean Validation annotation such as @Size(max = WebConsts.MAX_LENGTH) to provide server side validation.

Comment: @RobertHunt Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

In [Fuwesta](https://github.com/opensource21/fuwesta) I used a lot of tricks to reduce such duplication of information. My standard approach for this is to put the information into `MessageSource`. It's pretty easy and you have a nice access via `#{constant.nameMaxLength}`. 
Another approach would be to put this information always into the model.